# Can I apply a function on my list elements and store the list element and function return value in a key-value pair like a map using java streams?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a String List

```
List <String> Ids = [id1, ids2, id3];
```

and a Function

```
public List<String> getDays(String id) {
    // makes api call and fetch all the days in a list where id is present
    return list;
}
```

Now I want to perform getDays function on each of the list elements of IDs and store it in a map

```
Map<String, List<String> where String would be my Id from List(IDs) and 
List<String> would be the corresponding return value of getDays 
function on each Id
```

Once I get a map, I can use it for further operations like filtering it or checking of my ids falls on a particular day of the week.

I am aware it can be done using for loop, but I am more interested to know if there is any other method like streams or map utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toMap`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> Ids = Arrays.asList("id1", "id2", "id3");
    Map<String, List<String>> result = Ids.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), MyClass::getDays));

    System.out.println(result); // {id2=[id2_foo, id2_bar], id1=[id1_foo, id1_bar], id3=[id3_foo, id3_bar]}
}

/* DEMO METHOD */
public static List<String> getDays(String id) {
    return Arrays.asList(id + "_foo", id + "_bar");
}
```

Could be more understandable with the lambda notation

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = Ids.stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.toMap(id->id, id -> getDays(id)));
```